# How/what(criteria) to decide if the function should be private or public in CI

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, methods

How or what is the criteria to decide whether a function should be private or public.

Ive always coded without declaring the function so it was treated as public but it worked fine. However i read this on the guide,

> In some cases you may want certain functions hidden from public access. To make a function private, simply add an underscore as the name prefix and it will not be served via a URL request. For example, if you were to have a function like this:

How does the public access functions in the controller?

I have this line of code on every controller i make.

```
 if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

That prevents user from directly going through the controller and accessing the function via the url right?

I tried testing it, although i put that line of code, which works for view pages, if someone tried to access the view directly they would be sent away.

a private function gets an error while i can access function declared/assumed as public.

What is the criteria for functions to be 'must' private. Functions like accessing the database? or valuable data? like inputted information from user(sensitive information, like account details/username-password)?

Or should i just keep everything private so users cannot access the functions directly?

Example:

I have set a default controller named 'Main'

```
    public function index(){ 
    if($this->input->cookie('cookie',TRUE)){

    }
    else
    $this->load->view('login');
}
```

checks if cookie exist(if user is logged in already). If i set the index function to private, whenever i access the root/main folder, it cannot access. So i set it as public instead. Is my reasoning logical/reasonable?

```
public function login(){
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|callback_check_account');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
$this->load->view('login'); //i tried using redirect, but it does not pass the error message for validation
}else{

}
}
```

I declared the login function as public. Since the data needed there is submitted via the login form, also it cannot access from the callback function when its called.

```
 public function check_account($username){
    $data = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $_POST['password']);
    $result = $this->LoginModel->validate_account($data);
    if(empty($result)){
    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_account' , 'account does not exist');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('required' , '');
    return FALSE;
    } else if($result == 'invalid'){
    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_account' , 'password does not match');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('required' , '');
    return FALSE;
    } else if($result){
        $isLoggedin = array( 'username' => $result['username'] , 'type' => $result['status'] ,  'is_loggedin' => TRUE);
        $this->session->set_userdata($isLoggedin);
    return TRUE; }
    }
```

I declared it public, because if i declared it as private, my callback would cause a fatal error. Users can access this via the link `/Main/check_account/username`

Model:

```
 function validate_account($data){
        $this->db->select('username,password')->where('username' , $data['username']);
        $query = $this->db->get('admin')->result_array();
        if(!empty($query)){
            foreach($query as $row){
                if($data['password'] != $row['password']){
                return 'invalid'; } 
                else $query = array('username' => $row['username'] , 'password' => $row['password'] , 'status' => 'administrator');
 return $query; } 
        } else {
        $this->db->select('username,password')->where('username' , $data['username']);
        $query = $this->db->get('user_mst')->result_array();
        if(!empty($query)){
            foreach($query as $row){
                if($data['password'] != $row['password']){
                return 'invalid'; } 
                else $query['status'] = 'user'; return $query; } 
        } }
        }
```

EDITED: Changed the callback function to check whether the username inputted exist if not displays

> 'account does not exist'

, if it returns invalid, it displays

> 'password does not match'

if it returns $query, i set the session, plus the account status, since im creating only 1 login for both admin and user. I still don't know how i'll use the

> 'type'

in my session, but i just put it there incase ill need to check the session if the user is an admin or a user so they cannot access each other's pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want check_account being an action of the controller, you should use

```
public function _check_account($value) { ... }
```

and you invoke the callback like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|callback__check_account');
```

Note that there's two underscore '_' between 'callback' and 'check'. Furthermore, value of the form field submitted will be the parameter of your callback.

Comment: What difference does it bring?

I also edited my question, updated my code.

Comment: In CodeIgniter, public function starts with underscore in Controller will NOT expose as action to the web, i.e. /Main/_check_account/username will NOT call your public method _check_account($value). This allows you to write callback for the validator which will NOT be accessible via HTTP. You need to make the callback "public" (for the form validator) but protects from HTTP access like "private" does due to CodeIgniter's design.

Comment: Ah, i see, by the way, can you check why my session user data 'username' only prints as 'a' when i enter, print_r($this->session->all_userdata());

Comment: If i add _ in the beginning it shows an error for the validation error

'Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name.'

Comment: Are you sure you have two (2) underscores between "callback" and "check_account" ?

Comment: yes, i added another _/underscore. 

Lemme double check.... yep, validation error message error